# DB Design Best Practice: Return multiple rows with individual entries, or single row with multiple entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I'm looking to put together a matrix for both skills and education details. I'll have columns:

```
skills_mat_id | user_id | skill | competency_level | priority_level |
```

and something similar for education, where competency_level and priority_level can be blank in the forum (or NULL in the DB).

The question is should I be creating a separate line entry for each skill, i.e.:

```
1, user1, java, 7, 1
2, user1, php, 6, 2
3, user1, css, 4, 2
4, user1, python, 8, NULL
```

or should I have everything in the same column:

```
1|user1|java,php,css,python|7,6,4,8|1,2,2,NULL
```

I feel like the first option is a lot easier to implement (and less prone to mistakes with the front-end due to NULL/empty fields), but the second option seems more "efficient" and would return a single row for what could be a large list of skills. Does either option make a difference in performance? Is this more of a front-end problem? Or will the design decision have a substantial impact on the DB performance. I will be using MySQL for this, but I'm not particularly partial to any one database platform.

I am a bit concerned with something like updating or deleting a particular skill with the second option. I wouldn't be too sure on how to go about that in a way that would reduce the chances of accidentally deleting or updating the wrong part of the record.

We're looking at potentially having hundreds of thousands of users which would grow the "skills" or "education" tables substantially, and therefore was wondering if there's a best practice approach to a data set like this?

Comment: It's hard to go wrong with normalization.  If you don't know what that is, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing for single row reads vs multiple row is very deeply in the premature micro-optimization territory. If you index the table by `skill_mat_id` + `user_id`, a select by these columns should be very fast. Performance should not even be a concern.
On the other hand, if you store it in the comma format, it is hard to maintain, error-prone, and the front-end will, in any case, need to do the work for merging each skill name with proficiency. Always make it work first, design for modularity and elegance, and then optimize for performance only if needed.

If you absolutely need this performance, then benchmark it and see if the extra boost is worth it. It most likely is not, in the large scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple rows are better from the simplicity standpoint.

Otherwise you need to potentially loop on near every field.

Plus, what are you saving?  Not much.  If you put in a few rows, you'll get decent space savings.  If you put in a few hundred, you'll get better compression from a zip utility.

Code for simplicity, so it's easier to debug.